# Scroll DIV using buttons and mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scroll

I have a DIV with overflow scroll. And i want to add 2 buttons to scroll that div UP and DOWN. I only can find a way to or scroll with the mouse. Or scroll with buttons, because they want me to set overflow on hidden.

Is there a way to do both?

Comment: Please specify the scroll direction. Vertical or horizontal. And yes you can achieve this using jquery plugins. you should try googling.

Comment: It has to scroll vertical. I already had tried some jQuery plugins. But they do not do what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var step = 25;
var scrolling = false;

// Wire up events for the 'scrollUp' link:
$("#scrollUp").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
    // step.
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "-=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function (event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("up");
}).bind("mouseout", function (event) {
    scrolling = false;
});


$("#scrollDown").bind("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function (event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("down");
}).bind("mouseout", function (event) {
    scrolling = false;
});

function scrollContent(direction) {
    var amount = (direction === "up" ? "-=1px" : "+=1px");
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 1, function () {
        if (scrolling) {
            scrollContent(direction);
        }
    });
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s5mgX/1709/)